# Is it possible to set "full request" timeout on nginx?

Tags: nginx

I need to return "204 no content" 200ms after receiving request in case upstream's response has not been fully received yet, and I don't understand, which configuration directive can I use for this. I know about proxy_read/send_timeout options, but they only limit time between two read/write calls, not the time spent to send whole client request to the upstream and receive whole response from it.